# parameter estimation for linear regression with positive constraints

Tags: regression, python

How to estimate weights $w_i$ of linear summation with non-negative constraints?

$w_1*x_1 + w_2*x_2 + ... + w_n*x_n + e = y$

where $x_i$ and $y$ are observed data, $e$ is an error, and $w_i$ is the weight.

$x_i$, $y$, and $e$ are real vectors, all elements of those vectors are non-negative $(>=0)$. $w_i$ is real scalar values, greater than zero $(>0)$.

I want to find $w_i$ that minimize $|e|$.

I found some methods for constraints of $w_i$, but I could not find any method for $e$.

Comment: Does that help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385984/least-absolute-deviation-lad-with-non-negative-constraint https://bioconductor.statistik.tu-dortmund.de/packages/3.5/bioc/manuals/IPPD/man/IPPD.pdf

Comment: Do you want to minimize $|e|$ or $|e|^2$?  The two problems require rather different methods.  What do you mean by "any method for $e$"?  If indeed the components of $e$ are constrained to be non-negative, that suggests any model for $e$ would presuppose some special kind of distribution for those components--and certainly not a Normal one. What, then, are you supposing about that distribution?