# Least-squares fit of explicit parabolic sheet to scattered data points

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression, constrained-regression

For a given set of data points

$$\{(x_i, y_i, z_i)\}$$

there exists some

$$f_{ABC}(x,y)=Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2$$

that minimizes

$$\sum_i(f_{ABC}(x_i,y_i)-z_i)^2$$

$A$, $B$, and $C$ can be found quickly by directly solving/minimizing

$$(\begin{bmatrix}x_1^2&x_1y_1&y_2^2\\x_1^2&x_2y_2&y_2^2\\x_1^2&x_3y_3&y_3^2\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\\C\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\z_2\\z_3\\\vdots\end{bmatrix})^2$$

However, suppose we want to reduce the model's degrees of freedom from 3 to 2 by constraining $f_{ABC}$ to be a parabolic sheet. I think this would mean that $\begin{bmatrix}A&B&C\end{bmatrix}$ has to be of the form $\begin{bmatrix}U^2&2UV&V^2\end{bmatrix}$ so that $f_{ABC}(x,y)=(Ux+Vy)^2$.

It seems this is no longer solvable directly as a linear system.

What would be a performant/fast way to solve this constrained version of the problem?

### Background

The above question is a simpler version of my actual problem, which is to fit an explicit bicubic surface patch $g(x,y)=Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+D+Ex^3+Fy^3+Gx^2y+Hxy^2+Ix+Jy$ that is constrained to be quadratic (instead of cubic) along some (unknown) direction.

### Thoughts

Thinking further, my best idea currently is to

1. Directly fit an unconstrained quadratic surface i.e. find a solution in the span of $\begin{bmatrix}x_i^2&x_iy_i&y_i^2&1&x_i&y_i\end{bmatrix}$. Call this the "quadratic solution".
2. Orthogonalize the remaining basis vectors $\begin{bmatrix}x_i^3&y_i^3&x_i^2y_i&x_iy_i^2\end{bmatrix}$ w.r.t. the quadratic solution.
3. Somehow solve a constrained minimization within this reduced basis that is orthogonal to the quadratic solution, though I don't really know how to go about this.

I think the eventual cubic terms should be of the form $Ex^3+Fy^3+Gx^2y+Hxy^2=(Ux+Vy)^3$ so the constraint is $\begin{bmatrix}E&F&G&H\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}U^3&3U^2V&3UV^2&V^3\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Your question is confusing because graphs of the form you prescribe are not parabolic cylinders: they are parabolic *sheets.*  Are you sure you are asking the question you intended to ask?  As far as the "bicubic surface patch" goes, that really is a paraboloid (just drop the $x^3,$ $y^3$, $x^y,$ and $xy^2$ terms) but its vertex is constrained to be at the origin: is that intentional?

Comment: @whuber You are right on both counts. Sorry about that! I've edited. What mean by the constrained bicubic surface is that it avoids sigmoid-like bending in some (one unknown) direction.

Comment: Okay.  But any surface that is quadratic in all directions is quadratic, period: you seem to have a standard ordinary least squares model.

Comment: @whuber Can't it have parabolic cross-sections along one direction while having cubic cross-sections along other directions? Like $x^3+y^2$ for example.

Comment: In the $x^3+y^2$ case, consider the function along a generic line parameterized by a real number $t,$ $(x,y)=(at+b,ct+d).$ It is given by $$x^3+y^2=(at+b)^3+(ct+d)^2=a^3t^3+\cdots.$$ Evidently this is a cubic unless $a=0,$ which means that the function is quadratic *only* along lines in the $y$ direction: in all other directions it is cubic.

Comment: @whuber Yes: How to fit a cubic that is constrained to be quadratic in (at least) *one* direction? Or in the simple version: How to fit a paraboloid that is constrained to be constant in (at least) one direction (parabolic sheet)?

Comment: Could you please clarify?  Should the cubic be at most quadratic in one *direction* in the sense of being at most quadratic along all lines in that direction or should it be at most quadratic along at least one *line*?  The former is a more severe restriction.  Indeed, this discussion seems to skirt around a more basic question: what are you trying to model and what suggests these restrictions?

Comment: @whuber I'm trying to model physical surfaces that can flex easily in at most one direction but can still have "some curvature" in other directions. I used implicit quadric surfaces before, but now I want to allow "sigmoid" bending along at most one direction.

Comment: Physically, a surface like $z=x^3+y^2$ can't flex in any direction.  The ability to flex can be captured to some extent in the Gaussian curvature, which must be everywhere zero.  Such surfaces are said to be "developable."  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface.  Your question looks remarkably like https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/470479 (posted at nearly the same time): when there exist constants $w_i$ for which $z=f(w_1x+w_2 y)$ and $f$ is *any* smooth (but nonlinear) function, the surface will bend only in one direction.

Comment: @whuber In my case the surfaces are "somewhat developable". Gaussian curvature is present but localized dents are not.

Comment: @whuber I'm considering the product of a bivariate linear and a bivariate quadratic, which I think has 8 DoF compared to a cubic's 10 DoF. Not sure what the geometric implications are though. I'm going to put that into new question because I really wasn't clear with this one.

Comment: @whuber I've asked what I hope is a more well-posed question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/470890/least-squares-fit-of-the-product-of-a-bivariate-quadratic-linear-product-to-an-o). Sorry about the lack of clarity here and thank you for your questions.